# Stream.flatMap() from char[] to Character stream

Tags: java, java-stream, lambda

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.util.stream.*; 

class Playground { 

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        // Creating a character array 
        char arr[] = { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5' }; 

        // --------- Using Stream.of() --------- 
        // Will work efficiently 

        // to convert int array into Stream 
        Stream<char[]> stream = Stream.of(arr); 
        Stream<Integer> s = stream.flatMap((item)->new String(item).chars().mapToObj(a->(char)a));

        // Displaying elements in Stream 
        s.forEach(str -> System.out.print(str + " ")); 
    } 
}
```

I'm trying to convert a char[] into a stream of Characters with flatMap() but I got the following error

```
./Playground/Playground.java:14: error: incompatible types: inference variable R has incompatible bounds
        Stream<Integer> s = stream.flatMap((item)->new String(item).chars().mapToObj(a->(char)a));
                                          ^
    equality constraints: Integer
    lower bounds: U,Character
  where R,T,U are type-variables:
    R extends Object declared in method <R>flatMap(Function<? super T,? extends Stream<? extends R>>)
    T extends Object declared in interface Stream
    U extends Object declared in method <U>mapToObj(IntFunction<? extends U>)
1 error
```

Need help with understanding the error and how to accomplish this task. Specifically how this fix this line of code using flatMap() from char[] to Character stream.

```
Stream<Integer> s = stream.flatMap((item)->new String(item).chars().mapToObj(a->(char)a))
```

Edit: So the problems turns out not to be about Stream but lambda expression and I twitched the line and messed the typing up after fixing the lambda expression by accident. The original line was

```
Stream<Character> s = stream.flatMap(item->{new String(item).chars().mapToObj(a->(char)a);});
```

and the issue was missing return statement inside {}. Then I altered the line to

```
Stream<Integer> s = stream.flatMap((item)->new String(item).chars())
```

because I thought IntStream::mapToObj was causing troubles however I forgot the boxed() in the end and got another type error so I added back the IntStream::mapToObj and posted the question but forgot to change the Stream type back to Character. I got confused but the fog is cleared now.Thanks for the good answers.

Comment: Just do `Arrays.stream(array)`.

Comment: @WJS that doesn’t work with `char[]`.

Comment: @Holger Nuts!  Nor `short[]` nor `byte[]` either.  I keep forgetting that those types aren't overloaded.   I had to emend my answer below to fix.  Many thanks!.

Comment: Thanks guys. So the problems turns out not to be about Stream but lambda expression and I twitched the line and messed the typing up after fixing the lambda expression by accident. The original line was "Stream<Character> s = stream.flatMap(item->{new String(item).chars().mapToObj(a->(char)a);});" and the issue was missing return statement inside {}. I created new error after altering the line and the error mesg was a bit obscure, bad on my part. Again, thanks for the good answers:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used `Stream<Integer>` instead of `Stream<Character>`. If you want to use `Stream<Integer>`, you need to use [IntStream::boxed](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#boxed()) or `mapToObj(a -> Integer.valueOf(a))` as shown below:

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char arr[] = { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5' };

        Stream<char[]> stream1 = Stream.of(arr);
        Stream<Character> chars = stream1.flatMap(item -> new String(item).chars().mapToObj(a -> (char) a));
        chars.forEach(c -> System.out.print(c + " "));

        System.out.println();

        Stream<char[]> stream2 = Stream.of(arr);
        Stream<Integer> ints = stream2.flatMap(item -> new String(item).chars().boxed());
        ints.forEach(i -> System.out.print(i + " "));

        System.out.println();

        Stream<char[]> stream3 = Stream.of(arr);
        Stream<Integer> integers = stream3.flatMap(item -> new String(item).chars().mapToObj(a -> Integer.valueOf(a)));
        integers.forEach(i -> System.out.print(i + " "));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1 2 3 4 5 
49 50 51 52 53 
49 50 51 52 53
```

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful answer. I started with "Stream<Character> s = stream.flatMap(item->{new String(item).chars().mapToObj(a->(char)a);});" then switched to Stream<Integer>, turns out the {} is the problem. Seems that I cant use curly braces for 1 line lambda expression. "Stream<Character> s = stream.flatMap(item->new String(item).chars().mapToObj(a->(char)a));"so  this line works fine after removing the braces. Not completely sure why tho, I probably need to have a better understanding of generics before I understand this part of lambda expression.

Comment: @Luke when you want to use `{}`, you also have to make its contents a (`return`) statement: `item -> { return expression; }`

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Ohhhh yes, I was missing the return statement when using {}.Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there. Just replace `Stream<Integer>` to `Stream<Character>`, as you are casting to a `char` in your code.

However, the problem about your code is that **you are unnecessarily `flatMap`ping**. `Stream.of` expects an array with a reference type as its compound type. Further, `Arrays.stream` does not have an overload for `char[]`. You end up streaming over something that is guaranteed to be a single element. That element is your `char[]`.

You could just drop the `flatMap` operation, and directly convert the char array to a String.

```
String str = new String(arr);
Stream<Character> characterStream = str.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c);
```

Comment: Thanks!I got confused and made some silly mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

It’s not clear what you are trying to achieve with this detour of unnecessary operations. When you want to stream over an array, just start with that operation, instead of creating a single element stream, to chain `flatMap`, to chain another `map`.

Your code does already contain an approach for streaming over a `char[]` array, in the middle of the other operations, using the `String` constructor.

```
char[] arr = { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5' };

new String(arr).chars().forEach(i -> System.out.print(i + " "));
```

This will print the Unicode numbers. When you want to print characters instead, just change the terminal operation:

```
new String(arr).chars().forEach(i -> System.out.print((char)i + " "));
```

or

```
new String(arr).chars().forEach(i -> System.out.printf("%c ", i));
```

You can also use

```
new String(arr).chars().mapToObj(i -> (char)i).forEach(i -> System.out.print(i+" "));
```

but this bears boxing overhead, as it creates a `Stream<Character>`.

---

Note that `new String(arr)` bears a copying overhead, as it creates an immutable object. You can avoid this by using

```
CharBuffer.wrap(arr).chars().forEach(i -> System.out.printf("%c ", i));
```

Of course, you can insert as many curlicues as you want, e.g.

```
Stream.of(arr)
    .flatMapToInt(array -> CharBuffer.wrap(array).chars())
    .mapToObj(i -> (char)i) // returns a Stream<Character> not Stream<Integer>
    .forEach(i -> System.out.printf("%c ", i));
```

but there is no reason to do so.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer! Just started with lambda expression and Stream, testing out water here and there seeing what they do.

Answer (score 1):

- You can use `Arrays.stream()` for any array except byte, char or short.
- You can use `*Stream.of()` for any primitive array of type * where * is Int or Double, or Long.
- You can use `Stream.of()` for any Object array.

All of the following work as explained above.

```
Integer[] IntegerArray = {1,2,3,4};
Arrays.stream(IntegerArray).forEach(System.out::println);
Stream.of(IntegerArray).forEach(System.out::println);

int[] intArray = {1,2,3,4};
Arrays.stream(intArray).forEach(System.out::println);
IntStream.of(intArray).forEach(System.out::println);

double[] doubleArray = {1.2,3.3,4.5,6.7};
Arrays.stream(doubleArray).forEach(System.out::println);
DoubleStream.of(doubleArray).forEach(System.out::println);

String[] stringArray = {"a","b","c","d"};
Stream.of(stringArray).forEach(System.out::println);
```

To solve your actual problem, try this.

```
     // Creating a character array 
        char arr[] = { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5' }; 

        // --------- Using Stream.of() --------- 
        // Will work efficiently 

        // to convert int array into Stream 
        Stream<char[]> stream = Stream.of(arr); 


        // Displaying elements in Stream 
        s.forEach(str -> System.out.print(str + " ")); 
        Stream<Integer> s = stream.flatMapToInt((item)->(new String(item)).chars()).boxed();
        //or
        IntStream s = stream.flatMapToInt((item)->(new String(item)).chars());

        // Displaying elements in Stream 
        s.forEach(str -> System.out.print((char)str + " "));
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I'm trying to understand what went wrong with this line of code "Stream<Integer> s = stream.flatMap((item)->new String(item).chars().mapToObj(a->(char)a));"  and possible fixes. BTW, you can only use Arrays.stream() for primitive type arrays with the corresponding primitive type streams(intstream,longstream,doublestream).

Comment: Try this `IntStream s = stream.flatMapToInt((item)->(new String(item)).chars()).map(c->(char)c);`

Comment: Remember that `chars` are treated like `ints`  You will need to cast them to `char` again when you print them.  So the last map to char is of little use.

Comment: Very helpful, I got it now. Thanks!:)